# Unregister and register again in java NIO

Tags: java, nio

Is it possible to unregister and then register again later on with the same selector ?
I have to limit the amount of connection I accept and do key.cancel() to stop receiving OP_ACCEPT events.

```
server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
...
key.cancel()
...
```

If a connection is closed, I cant run register(..) again, getting a
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException

Javadoc for register(..) : throw CancelledKeyException if this channel is currently registered with the given selector but the corresponding key has already been cancelled

What is the way to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? It sounds like you're forgetting to reregister your channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the bits you want to clear in the key's `interestOps`: for example `key.interestOps(0)`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, is there was a way to just close it and having connection attempt end up with "Connection refused" without closing currently accepted connection ?

Comment: Of course, just close the ServerSocket/ServerSocketChannel. It doesn't affect already-accepted connections.